# Enforcing single subtype SQL table for supertype table

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I have a supertype table called "vehicles".  I also have three subtype tables called "airplanes", "automobiles", and "bicycles", and one and only one of these subtype tables must be linked to the vehicles supertype table (or in other words, must use the vehicles primary key ID as its primary key ID).

How should this be modeled to enforce this behavior?

EDIT Proposed schema recommended by Mike Brant.

```
-- MySQL Script generated by MySQL Workbench
-- 05/25/16 09:20:17
-- Model: New Model    Version: 1.0
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ;
USE `mydb` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`vehicle_types`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`vehicle_types` (
  `type` CHAR(8) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`type`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`vehicles`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`vehicles` (
  `idvehicles` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` CHAR(8) NOT NULL,
  `data` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idvehicles`),
  INDEX `fk_vehicles_vehicle_types_idx` (`type` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_vehicles_vehicle_types`
    FOREIGN KEY (`type`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`vehicle_types` (`type`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`airplanes`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`airplanes` (
  `vehicles_idvehicles` INT NOT NULL,
  `data_for_airplanes` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`vehicles_idvehicles`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_airplanes_vehicles1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`vehicles_idvehicles`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`vehicles` (`idvehicles`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`automobiles`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`automobiles` (
  `vehicles_idvehicles` INT NOT NULL,
  `data_for_automobiles` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`vehicles_idvehicles`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_automobiles_vehicles1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`vehicles_idvehicles`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`vehicles` (`idvehicles`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`bicycles`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`bicycles` (
  `vehicles_idvehicles` INT NOT NULL,
  `data_for_bicycles` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`vehicles_idvehicles`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_bicycles_vehicles1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`vehicles_idvehicles`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`vehicles` (`idvehicles`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Comment: Need much more information here to make suggestions as to schema.  Can you start with your current proposed schema?

Comment: @MikeBrant  Please see edited original question.

Answer (score 0):

I think inserting in vehicles and any of other sub types should be simultaneously. Therefore you can get the vehicle ID and put as  new sub-type PK ID. If you have all information at the same time you can create a transcation and insert the vehicle record first then the sub-type record. Then commit your transscation otherwise rollback it. IF you want to know which record belongs to which sub-type table record you can add a column to your vehicle table that for example can have 3 different values such as 0,1,2 that shows which record belongs to which sub-table. Enum in java can be used in something like that for more clarification

Comment: Does `0,1,2` correspond to `airplanes, automobiles, bicycles`?  Should any additional foreign key constraints or triggers be used?

Comment: yes they correspond to your sub-types. No there is no need to foreign keys. But you can put a control (check) on your vehicle table that only 0,1 and 2 should be inserted in this field. However if you have many tables with this features you can create a table for storing any sub-type value and add its foreign key to your table here e.g Vehicle.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your proposed schema, I see no reason whatsoever for you to have separate tables for each vehicle type, or even a separate table to contain the allowable vehicle types. Your vehicle-specific tables are all basically the same thing meaning you can easily collapse into a single table, and you can use ENUM field to enforce allowable vehicle types.

Why not just have a single vehicles table like the following?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`vehicles` (
  `idvehicles` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` ENUM('airplane', 'automobile', 'bicycle') NOT NULL,
  `data` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idvehicles`),
  INDEX `fk_vehicles_vehicle_types_idx` (`type` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

This approach totally eliminates 4 of your 5 tables, meaning you no longer have to consider using joins, foreign key constraints, etc. when performing CRUD operations against these records.

Comment: Mike,  I am sorry, I used the same `data` column in each subtype table, but did not mean to imply that each of the three subtypes will have only a single column.  In reality data for airplanes, automobiles, and bicycles will be very different and will require different quantities of columns.

Comment: @user1032531 Understood. In that case, you probably should add information to your original question around expected call patterns needed to write and retrieve this data.  The way in which your application needs to work with this data will determine what schema may be most appropriate.  For example, do you expect at any point to have to list all available vehicles regardless of type together in a single list, or would you only ever be querying within single vehicle types?

Comment: I will need to list all vehicles regardless of type, and will wish to display the type in this list.  The type "can" be determined by inspecting which subtype table is joined to it, but "probably" should include an additional type column to enforce only one type.  Also, vehicles will be joined to other tables which is my primary reason to use a supertype/subtype design (another benefit is saving common data).

Answer (score 0):

To enforce exclusive subtypes, copy the `type` indicator into each of the subtype tables and use composite foreign key constraints:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`airplanes` (
  `vehicles_idvehicles` INT NOT NULL,
  `type` CHAR(8) NOT NULL,
  `data_for_airplanes` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`vehicles_idvehicles`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_airplanes_vehicles1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`vehicles_idvehicles`, `type`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`vehicles` (`idvehicles`, `type`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Next you need to restrict the value of `type` in each table.  Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't support check constraints, so you would need to use triggers:

```
DELIMITER ;;

CREATE TRIGGER airplanes_insert_type_check
    BEFORE INSERT ON airplanes
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
    IF NEW.`type` != 'airplane' THEN 
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
            SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Invalid type in airplanes';
    END IF; 
END;;

CREATE TRIGGER airplanes_update_type_check
    BEFORE UPDATE ON airplanes
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
    IF NEW.`type` != 'airplane' THEN 
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
            SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Invalid type in airplanes';
    END IF; 
END;;

DELIMITER ;
```

Thus, the `type` indicator in the supertype table will match only one of the subtype tables' `type` indicators due to the trigger restrictions, and will be enforced via foreign key constraint, preventing overlapping subtypes.

Comment: Thanks reaanb,  Why add `type` to the subtype table and not just the supertype table?

Comment: I updated my answer.  The type indicator in the supertype will match only one of the subtype tables' type indicators due to the trigger restrictions, and will be enforced via foreign key constraint, preventing overlapping subtypes.

Comment: Ah, so the problem with my original approach would be that the database allows more than one subtype table to be joined to a given supertable record?

Comment: The problem is not with joins.  You had no constraints to tell the subtypes what they were expected to be.

Comment: I did have "and one and only one of these subtype tables must be linked to the vehicles supertype table".  It seems that your trigger might enforce this.