# How many tables will the Relational Schema have for this ER Diagram?

Tags: database, schema, erd

I have the following as my ER Diagram. I am still learning DBMS, and trying to translate this ER Diagram to a Relational Schema. I know that each entity in the ER Diagram will have a separate table. However, I am not sure what to do about the relationship for this particular ER Diagram. We were told that each relationship between the entities will have a table too. Therefore, do I need to make separate for relationships in this ER Diagram as well? But, there are no attributes of the relationship. Also, I am having a confusion in what sort of relationship is this exactly? Is this one to many?

I am attaching the link to the picture of the ER Diagram. Please guide me in the right direction. Thanks! [image]

Answer (score 1):

Your diagram isn't an ER diagram in the original sense of that term.  In the entity-relationship model, relationships are associations among entity sets and were meant to be implemented as tables.  For example, your `AUTHOR_BOOK`, `CAST` and `PURCHASE` tables are relationship tables that associate two entity sets each (keep in mind that relationships aren't limited to just two entity sets).  Note how the relationships are represented using the keys of the entity sets e.g. `(actorID, inventID)`.  The same pattern can be found in some of your other tables, i.e. `(inventID, publisher)`, `(inventID, director)`, `(inventoryID, genre)`, `(inventoryID, supplier)`, `(receiptID, inventID)` and `(receiptID, customerID)`.  These are your relationships - not the crow's foot lines which are just foreign key constraints.  In Chen's original notation, the relationships would be indicated using diamond shapes between and connected to the two entity types.  Also, Chen would've made a separate relationship table (aka junction table) for each of these relationships.

Your table diagram shows 14 tables.  Following Chen's method, there would be 19 tables:

[image: Inventory ER diagram]

Your title references a relational schema.  Note that relational schemas are not restricted to the entity-relationship model, but can represent any set of normalized tables (1NF or higher).  The number of tables would partially depend on the level of normalization.

> But, there are no attributes of the relationship.

This is not correct.  Your `Purchase` relationship shows two attributes - `quantity` and `amountPaid`.  Note that **an attribute is a mapping from an entity or relationship set to a value set**.  Thus, I'm not counting the entity keys as attributes of the relationship.  I also modeled `Book`'s `pubYear` as an attribute of the relationship between `Book` and `Publisher`.

In practice, I would probably denormalize relations with the same determinant, which give a physical schema similar to your original diagram, though implementing every relationship table separately does have some advantage in easing schema changes when relationship cardinalities change.

Comment: can you help me identify all the Entity Relations and Relationship relations from the updated complete post? Thanks! :)

Comment: the tables for relationships like receipt_customer and inventory_genre will be containing the primary keys of the two connecting entities, right?

Comment: just one more thing. The entity Inventory itself is divided into two parts. One is Book and DVD. While writing the SQL commands for creating tables for these three entities, will if I have to write some additional command apart from the normal Create Table commands in order to show this hierarchy relationship?

Comment: Subtypes have the same primary key attributes as their supertypes, and that's normally controlled by a foreign key constraint.  If you want to enforce exclusive subtypes, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37442413/enforcing-single-subtype-sql-table-for-supertype-table.  If your target DBMS supports check constraints, use that instead of triggers.